# How to use drop down menu to change PHP object variable?

Tags: php, forms

The title may not be the best way to word this question, so please let me know if I can improve it.

What I am trying to do is use a drop down menu to change the value of a PHP object.

In the example below, I want $selected to be assigned as the "value" of the the menu option selected.

```
  $selected = $_GET['program_select'];
```

Here is the drop down menu:

```
  <select id="programs_select" name="programs_select">
    <option>Select a Different Month</option>  
    <?
     foreach($pagedata->programs as $programs){
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$programs->id?>"><?=$programs->title?></option> 
    <?    
    }
    ?>
  </select>
```

How can I send this value to the server and reload the page using the selected value?

For example, if the 2nd option is selected and it's id is 2 the result would be:

```
$selected = 2;
```

FYI, this is being used to dynamically generate the output data for a thumbnail menu.  The "program" being displayed would be determined by the value in the option selected.

Comment: Where is the PHP object variable you want to change?

Comment: The PHP object $selected is in the controller for the view page.  It is being used in the controller to determine the content output.

Comment: Okay, your problem is that you ask two questions at once. Instead ask two questions separated. Which of your two questions is more imortant: a) how to transfer a html form value to the server and put it into a PHP variable or b) how to do a redirect in PHP?

Comment: I want to direct the value to the server and load the page based on that value.

Comment: So a). What prevents you from doing so?

Comment: I don't entirely know what I'm doing.

Comment: Okay, as far as you're concerned about PHP, it's written here: [Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <select id="programs_select" name="programs_select" onchange="ihavechanges(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option>Select a Different Month</option>  
    <?
     foreach($pagedata->programs as $programs){
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$programs->id?>"><?=$programs->title?></option> 
    <?    
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function ihavechanged(towhat)
     {
     document.location.href = "reload.php?id="+towhat;
     }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="programs_select" name="programs_select">
    <option>Select a Different Month</option>  
    <?
    $selected = $_GET['program_select'];
    foreach($pagedata->programs as $programs){
        $seld = ($selected == $program-id) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="'.$programs->id.'" '.$seld.'>'.$programs->title.'</option>';     
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The object $selected is in the controller for the page being viewed, not the actual php file.

Comment: What do you mean by controller? You need to store the program_select. If it is not in the same http request as your form, then you have to store it in a $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GET in the php side. So, if you just want to know how to pass the value to your php file, then put your select tag into a form and add a submit button.

```
<form id="your_id" name="your_id" method="get" action="your_controller/your_function_name">
 <select id="programs_select" name="programs_select">
    <option>Select a Different Month</option>  
    <?
     foreach($pagedata->programs as $programs){
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$programs->id?>"><?=$programs->title?></option> 
    <?    
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

In your controller, echo something based on the value.

> $selected = $_GET['program_select'];

However, if your want to change the contents in the same page without refresh. You may need ajax call to do that, and I recommend the jQuery ajax api (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$("select#programs_select").live('change', function(){
        var id = $("select#programs_select").val();        
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "your_controller/the_funstion_name?programs_select=" + id,
                data: "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function(msg) {
                $("#your_thumbnail_menu_id").html(msg); 
                },
                error: function() {
                alert("Error! Ajax failed");
                }
            }); 

        });
```

In your controller side, echo the html you need at last.
e.g:

```
$selected = $_GET['program_select']; 
$html = "<ul><li>your menu  $selected</li>";
$html .="<li>which depends on the id you got!</li></ul>";
echo $html;
```